# "bash: yamllint: command not found" after installing yamllint and trying to use it

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, lint

after installing the last version of pip and successfully installing yamllint using

```
pip install yamllint
```

when I'm trying to use yamlling by writing in the terminal

```
yamllint .
```

or

```
yamllint file.yml
```

I'm getting the error

```
bash: yamllint: command not found
```

why is that?